# jquery ui autocomplete is not listing result

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

i am using jquery ui v1.10.3 and style v1.10.3 library.
jquery klibrary version is v1.9.1

this is my text box

```
<input type="text" name="txtCustomer" id="txtCustomer" />
```

and  i have this js

```
$("#txtCustomer").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/kpanel/handlers/content.aspx?act=getCustomer&d=' + d,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: { name: encodeURI(request.term) },
                    success: function (z) {
                        response($.map(z.Data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Name,
                                value: item.Name
                        }));
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (event, ui) {
                $("#lblType").html(ui.item.TypeName);
                $("#lblCode").html(ui.item.CustomerCode);
            },
            open: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-all").addClass("ui-corner-top");
            },
            close: function () {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-all");
            }
        });
```

and this is my result Json Data

```
{
    "Data": [
        {
            "Name": "Kolya Husten",
            "CustomerCode": "MT20132645",
            "TypeName": "Normal",
            "Email": "kolya@husten.com",
            "Telephone": "0(234)567-89-45",
            "MobilePhone": "0(234)567-89-76",
            "DiscountRatio": "0"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Loya Mantus",
            "CustomerCode": "MT20132602",
            "TypeName": "Normal",
            "Email": "loya@mantus.com",
            "Telephone": "0(212)268-02-22",
            "MobilePhone": "0(536)448-96-67",
            "DiscountRatio": "10"
        }
    ]
}
```

everything look good but result is not displayed as shown image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i have found the error.

in my style.css file i have this line

```
body { background: #fff;  color: #393939; font-family: Arial; font-size:0px; line-height: 0; }
```

because of font-size property result list was not shown. i changed this line like this.

```
body { background: #fff;  color: #393939; font-family: Arial; line-height: 0; }
```

and it worked.

thanks anyway.